# How to adjust the size of presented view - Swift 5 (Xcode)

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, presentviewcontroller

I have a **button** which will lead a to collection view controller **drawDetails_VC**.

```
func showController() {

    let drawDetails_VC = DrawDetails(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white

    let navController = CustomNavigationController(rootViewController: drawDetails_VC)
    present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

After updating to **Swift 5**, the presented collection view **Page Sheet** is not covering the full screen.
[image]

I tried hours but didn't get what I want.

How can the presented sheet **Page Sheet** cover the whole screen and not as above image.
And how can I get programmaticlly the width of the presented Controller **Page Sheet**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your view controller's modal presentation style to `.fullScreen` or `.overFullScreen`. Try the code example below.

```
func showController() {
    let drawDetails_VC = DrawDetails(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
    let navController = CustomNavigationController(rootViewController: drawDetails_VC)
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot AMIT, really appreciated. this is what I want. is there a way to know how to get programmatically the width of presented controller?

Comment: id for new question is 60476255